# React Native does not play local videos

Tags: react-native, video, react-native-video

I'm trying to play a video playlist. But if I debug on my device the video is not loaded, only if i aply videos from over the network or if i use 'require' like this:

```
<Video repeat={true} source={require('./StaticVideo.mp4')} style={styles.tokenVideo} muted={true} resizeMode="cover" ></Video>
```

But I want to play local videos from the downloads directory like this:

```
<Video source={{ uri: `${fs.dirs.DownloadDir}/video.mp4` }} onProgress={this.onProgress.bind(this)} progressUpdateInterval={1000} onEnd={this.onVideoEnd.bind(this)} style={styles.video} ref={this.video} resizeMode="stretch" muted={true}></Video>
```

But I don't see anything. On the emulator it is working and showing me the videos, but not on my real device.

Thanks.

Comment: what library are you using to display the video?

Comment: I am using the "react-native-video" library.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Just needed to add the permissions to read from external storage.